# Is there any way to add hover effect on different svg paths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Is there a way to add hover effects on the paths of the SVG file from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Italy_map_with_regions.svg. ?  The final goal is to get an interactive map of clickable regions so that when mousing over a region, info about the region appears.

Comment: I suppose the paths have no fill. Try adding [pointer-events: all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for the paths.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a svg that has different path for every different region and you can add a id or class to that path and add a hover effect on it by javascript or by css only.